# Unable to load a saved JButton

Tags: java, swing, serialization, nullpointerexception, jbutton

I'm making a program that is saving an array of JButtons to a file .btn. here is the code that is being saved:

```
package avtech.software.compunav;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Buttons implements Serializable {
public static Button[] buttons = new Button[15];

public Buttons() {
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i] = new Button();
        buttons[i].setText("Unassigned");
    }
}

public JButton[] getButtons() {
    return buttons;
}

public JButton getButton(int index) {
    return buttons[index];
}

public void setButtonText(String txt, int index) {
    buttons[index].setText(txt);
}

public void setButtonAction(String action, int index) {

}

public void save() {
    try {
        File dir = new File(Core.baseDir + "/bin/buttons.btn");

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        if (dir.exists())
            dir.delete();

        oos.writeObject(this);

        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

`Button` is a class that extends JButton, and here is that code:

```
 package avtech.software.compunav;

 import java.awt.Desktop;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;

 import javax.swing.JButton;

 import CompuNav.main.Dialogs;

 public class Button extends JButton implements ActionListener {

private String action = "";

public Button() {
    addActionListener(this);
}

public void setAction(String s) {
    action = s;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if (action.equals(""))
        return;

    File file = new File(action);
    Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();

    try {
        dt.open(file);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Dialogs.msg("Could not open " + action);
    }
}

 }
```

Basically, the code is saving. there is a file called buttons.btn in the correct directory. The problem is, when I use the load method here:

```
 try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(baseDir
                + "/bin/buttons.btn");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        buttonsClass = (Buttons) ois.readObject();

        ois.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

after making a new object of the Buttons and saving it, I get a nullPointerException when trying to call `buttonsClass.getButton(0);`, implying that the JButtons are not saved when i save the class.

Any reason as to why, and any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static Button[] buttons = new Button[15];
```

This variable should not be static if you want it to be serialized.